# "Ay me" origins and usage?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I have been recently reading Romeo and Juliet, and towards the beginning of the balcony scene, Juliet says

> Ay me.

What does this phrase mean and when was it first created/used?

Comment: Ay me: 
From Middle French aymi.

Interjection



(now archaic) Expressing grief, sorrow. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ay_me

Comment: @Gio please post as an answer.

Comment: More commonly expressed as "Ah me!" (The Italian for _Alas_ is still _Ahimè_.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, English was heavily influenced by French. It may therefore be best to look to France for an explanation:

> [Glossaire de la Langue Romaine](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=X9VLAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%22aymi%22++%C3%A9tymologie&source=bl&ots=Lh980XQtaH&sig=ACfU3U2n3FWDad7zQ0IqCzvyBOx1iIofIA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj59OrbsM2CAxULSUEAHVxUApY4ChDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22aymi%22%20%20%C3%A9tymologie&f=false)
> has:
> *Ainmi, aimi, aimini, aymi, emi, heimi, hemi; Exclamation. Le pronom mi, moi, réuni à l'optatif du verbe aier, aider, a produit ces exclamations composées.*
>
> Loosely translated, this says:
>
> *Ainmi, aimi, aimini, aymi, emi, heimi, hemi*; Exclamation.
> The pronoun *mi* or *moi*, joined to the optative form of the verb *aier*, or *aider*, (to help) has produced these joined exclamations.

The optative form is a grammatical mood that indicates a wish or hope regarding a given action. Hence we may understand Juliet to be saying "*I hope I may be helped*", which fits the context of her difficult amorous predicament.
.

Comment: The OP also asked when it was first used in English.

Comment: @Heartspring Indeed they do but, lacking reliable information, I cannot answer that part.